# How to make asyncio tasks ignore CancelledError

Tags: python-asyncio

If client closes connection asyncio tasks receive `CancelledError` and request processing stops. Is there any way to finish all the tasks and ignore connection errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all running tasks with `asyncio.Task.all_tasks()`. To finish task you should call `cancel()` on it and await task done (suppressing `CancelledError`). Full solution:

```
pending = asyncio.Task.all_tasks()
for task in pending:
    task.cancel()
    with suppress(asyncio.CancelledError):
        await task
```